# Why I can not use seekg(0, ifstream::end) when I open a linux system file as ifstream

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, seekg

I want using C++ to get the machine's CPU information, and my code is:

```cpp
    ifstream cpu_info_file("/proc/cpuinfo", ifstream::in|ifstream::binary);
    streampos sp = cpu_info_file.tellg();
    cout << sp << endl;

    cpu_info_file.seekg(0, ifstream::end);
    sp = cpu_info_file.tellg();
    cout << sp << endl;

    cpu_info_file.seekg(-10, ifstream::cur);
    sp = cpu_info_file.tellg();
    cout << sp << endl;

    cpu_info_file.seekg(0, ifstream::beg);
    sp = cpu_info_file.tellg();
    cout << sp << endl;
```

but I got the output:

```
0
-1
-1
-1
```

after that I copy /proc/cpuinfo to my project path, and modify the code:

```
ifstream cpu_info_file("cpuinfo",ifstream::in|ifstream::binary);
```

and I got the right output:

```
0
10424
10414
0
```

I spent a whole day trying to figure out the reason, but if I open any file under `/proc` and use `file.seekg(n, ifstream::end)`, the return of `file.tellg()` will always be **-1** and I can not move the streampos anymore.

**So why I can not read the file under /proc as the file under my project directory?**

Comment: Most special files in `/proc` do not have fixed size and their content is generated on the fly while the process `read()`-s from them. It is not possible to seek from the end of such files.

Comment: So is there any way if I want to get the last few lines of the file in /proc without reading the whole file?

Comment: Without reading the whole file - I don't think so.

Comment: All right, Thank you!